# Read Config File in :NET

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

I want to read this Config File with c#

```
<Wo>
 <Od name="rene" id="32442">
  <Ider>
    <Suc name="Oda"/>
    <Fed name="Wor"/>
  </Ider>
  <Proc id="756545">
     <add name="var" type="int"/>
     <add name="zar" type="string"/>
  </Proc>
</Od>
<Od name="mene" id="4562">
  <Ider>
    <Suc name="Zida"/>
    <Fed name="Worm"/>
  </Ider>
  <Proc id="7985">
     <add name="tar" type="bool"/>
     <add name="mar" type="string"/>
  </Proc>
</Od>
</Wo>
```

Comment: That's totally doable. What have you tried? What's tripping you up?

Comment: I want to read **this** Config File with c#  What file ?

Comment: Sounds good.  Go for it.

Comment: Right, what is :NET? Never heard of it...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - as you see by some of the comments above, the community tends to react poorly if you don't actualyy ask a question. We also like it if you tell us what you have tried yourself and why you think that wasn't adequate. Good luck for the future.

Comment: this is config file i need a ConfigurationSection with a ConfigurationElementCollection

Answer (score 2):

There are many options in C# for reading structured data files.  This appears to be XML, in which case [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) would provide a simple means of reading this data.

Comment: this custom configuration section for my .NET4 application.And i want to read it with ConfigurationSection,ConfigurationCollection and ConfigurationElement.How can i do it

Comment: @TrsUix You'd have to restructure it into a form that ConfigurationElement understands

Comment: <configurationFile>
     <Wo>
      <Od name="rene" id="32442">
        <Ider>
          <Suc name="Oda"/>
          <Fed name="Wor"/>
       </Ider>
        <Proc id="756545">
           <add name="var" type="int"/>
           <add name="zar" type="string"/>
        </Proc>
      </Od>
      <Od name="mene" id="4562">
         <Ider>
           <Suc name="Zida"/>
           <Fed name="Worm"/>
        </Ider>
        <Proc id="7985">
          <add name="tar" type="bool"/>
          <add name="mar" type="string"/>
        </Proc>
      </Od>
     </Wo>
    </configurationFile>

Comment: this is config file i need a ConfigurationSection with a ConfigurationElementCollection

Comment: @TrsUix That format is not compatible with how ConfigurationElement works.  You'll need to manually parse the XML (via XDocument or similar) or change configuration formats.

Comment: i know it just a piece of my Configuration File i need to read the Data for the tag <Wo> </Wo> and save it in 2 List

Answer (score 0):

You could use *split* or *regex* to read this file, i would go with Split.

**For example:**

```
  string strReturn;      
  strReturn = str.Split(new string[] { "Od name=\"mene\""}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
  strReturn = strReturn.Split(new string[] { "<\Od>" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
  return strReturn;
```

Comment: this is custom configuration section for my .NET4 application.And i want to read it with ConfigurationSection,ConfigurationCollection and ConfigurationElement.How can i do it